# CSS - Change background positioning depending of size

Tags: css, background-image, positioning

I have a div section with a background image. The div section has a variable width but a fixed height.
The background images has always the same with as the div section and is positioned at the bottom center.

```css
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7f7f7f;
}

footer::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("./img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: bottom center;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

If now the div section goes to width, the background image becomes to height and is cut on the top.
I would like to change the position to top center if the image becomes to height and so cut the bottom of the image. Is there a solution to achiev this effect?

Comment: Please share your HTML code too.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek : the HTML code only has the <footer></footer> tags.

Comment: At the moment I solved it with the @media in the css code. But maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change the background-size from 100% auto to 'contain' like this:

```
 background-size: contain;
```

Comment: this does not realy solve my problem, because this way the picture doesn't fit on the width.

Comment: I suggest you to add the pic as background to the div without using ::before